# Logic / Algorithm for this Series

Tags: c++, arrays, character

I have an array of characters from a to z, my task is to extract the vowels out of this array, the series that will extract the indexes of vowels goes like this, **1, 5, 9, 15, 21, 25...** i am unable to create this series through loops, these numbers are actually the vowels in the array.

I don't want Vowel Matching technique, i want the logic for the sequence given above.

Comment: Are you trying to find a mathematical way of creating that sequence without having to have it in your code explicitly?

Comment: Why can't you just loop through the character array comparing every element to the constants 'a' 'e' 'i' 'o' 'u'?

Comment: Have you considered `int vowels[] = {1, 5, 9, 15, 21, 25};`?

Comment: why you have to use a loop? What's wrong with int a[6] = {1,5,9,15,21,25}?

Comment: Just need the algorithm for 1,5,9,15,21,25 forget about the vowels.

Comment: One possible creation-rule is +4,+4,+6,+6,+4,+4,... But there could be other rules as well. More terms are needed to know better.

Comment: Forgetting about the vowels:
what's with the "..." after the 25. I have a hard time figuring out how the sequence is supposed to be continued. If it isn't, this is why an algorithmic solution does not really make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this algorithmically, you could:

```
int v = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", v);
    v += 4 + (i & 2);
}
```

...but I'm not sure I see the point.

Comment: what is the purpose of the & operator? :)  if you can explain a little.

Comment: I'm not going to elaborate further. It's enough to just give you an answer; you'll have to figure out how it works yourself.

Comment: May be some one else can explain.

Comment: @Imran -- had to run this through the debugger to work it out but its looking for the second bit from the right being set. So 1 = '001', 2 = '010' , 3 = '100' , 4 = '101' and 5 = '110'. So if i = 2 or 3 the next number in the sequence ( 3rd and 4th)  will be incremented by 6 rather than 4.

Comment: I understand it,  (i & 2) will either return 0 or 1 in binary that would be 2 or 0 so it will be adding 2 or 0 to 4 in either cases, i must say you are a genius, work well done, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the solution proposed by **Greg Hewgill** to be the more appropiate one, where you have `int vowels[] = {1, 5, 9, 15, 21, 25};` and `vowels[i]` is your function. However, if you want a math function Wolfram Alpha proposes:

```
(z(z((9-5z)z-11)+5))/((z-1)^4)+1
```

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C+5%2C+9%2C+15%2C+21%2C+25

That said, I don't see a point in using it instead of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can doubtlessly find a formula for the sequence, but is that the
right approach?  Whether a character is a vowel or not isn't determined
by whether it is a member of a sequence or not; it is purely arbitrary,
and not necessarily the same from one language to another: y is a vowel
in some languages, a consonant in others, and can be either in English;
27, 28 and 29 don't exist in English, but are vowels in Swedish, etc.